# The connection is not tested with configuration.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery", "SELECT 1");

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0

I set up connection programmatically.

```
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + dbName);
    LOG.debug("{} Connection URL is jdbc:mysql://{}:{}/{}", Options.TAG, host, port, dbName);
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", user);
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", pass);
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery", "SELECT 1");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.min_size", minConns);
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_size", maxConns);
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements", "50");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.pool_size", "1");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.cache.provider_class", "org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
    configuration.addResource("TransactionBean.hbm.xml");
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
            configuration.getProperties()).build();

    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

I get warning

```
WARN BasicResourcePool:1851 - com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@6972975c
-- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. 
While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the
maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt 
exception: 
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: 
Communications link failure
```

As you can see from comfiguration the connection must be tested in accordance to
   configuration.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery", "SELECT 1");
However it's not tested. Why SELECT 1 is not queried?

My goal is to obtain the exception if the connection hasn't been established.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh. well you'll never see a Connection test fail if Connections haven't even been acquired. clients will simply fail to check out a Connection from the pool. (i missed the WARNING that was troubling you when i first answered, i guess.) there have to be Connections in the pool before any Connection test can be run. With `testConnectionOnCheckout=true`, every Connection clients see will have been tested. But that's an entirely different issue that Connection acquisitions failing (the WARNING above)

if your pool fails to acquire ANY Connections, clients will just hang or timeout (if you've set `checkoutTimeout`). if the pool acquires Connections in general, but occasionally fails to be able to for some reason that, unusually, doesn't invalidate already acquired Connections, then tests will be run as normal, and will pass, while attempt to acquire new Connections sometimes fail. if failed acquisition signals that the DBMS is down or unavailable, you'll see both this warning AND Connection tests failures when clients try to use now-broken Connections.

Answer (score 0):

you've set a `preferredTestQuery` that would be used if Connections were set to be tested, but you've not actually specified any Connection testing. to do that, you need to set `testConnectionOnCheckin`, `testConnectionOnCheckout`, and/or `idleConnectionTestPeriod`. Please see  http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing

Comment: I added 
testConnectionOnCheckin = false
testConnectionOnCheckout = true
idleConnectionTestPeriod = 0
I can from logs that c3p0 pool was initialized with this parameters. But I still didn't get the exception. Maybe I need to run some method to test explicitly run connection test?

Comment: oh. well you'll never see a Connection test fail if Connections haven't even been acquired. clients will simply fail to check out a Connection from the pool. (i missed the WARNING that was troubling you when i first answered, i guess.) there have to be Connections in the pool before any Connection test can be run. With `testConnectionOnCheckout=true`, every Connection clients see will have been tested. But that's an entirely different issue that Connection acquisitions failing (the WARNING above).

Comment: if your pool fails to acquire ANY Connections, clients will just hang or timeout (if you've set `checkoutTimeout`). if the pool acquires Connections in general, but occasionally fails to be able to for some reason that, unusually, doesn't invalidate already acquired Connections, then tests will be run as normal, and will pass, while attempt to acquire new Connections sometimes fail. if failed acquisition signals that the DBMS is down or unavailable, you'll see both this warning AND Connection tests failures when clients try to use now-broken Connections.

Comment: Thank, now it's clear. Can You move your comments to the answer and I will mark it as the right answer?